# Nginx block access to referring url

Tags: linux, nginx, dns

I've discovered a domain is pointing to my servers IP address as an A-record.

I've tried to implement various measures to have have it blocked. I can block it accessing assets on the server i.e loading JS/CSS files and I can block it when a link is accessed from within the site. I'm guessing that when the page is first loaded it's not technically a referrer? But when a link is clicked and it changes page then it is?

What I've tried:

```
if ($http_referer ~* domaintoblock)
    {  return 403;   }
```

and

```
valid_referers none blocked server_names
   *.mydomain.com;

if ($invalid_referer) {
    return 403;
}
```

Both of these have the same effect. All assets loaded are blocked and any subsequent page access is blocked but the initial access isn't blocked.

Ideally I'd like to block anything that isn't the `server_name` variable I've listed in my `site-enabled/default` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to add a [catch-all server block](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html):

```
server {
    listen       80  default_server;
    server_name  "";
    return       444;
}
```

The `444` status code will close the connection without sending a response.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to simply configure a server block for this name and return a 444 or 403.